# Why cant I run apt install on mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, apt

When I type `apt install ffmpeg` in Terminal, (I am using the latest Mac OS update) I get following error: `Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`

How do I solve that?

Comment: Is it `apt` or `apt-get` command for installing `ffmpeg`? Or try with [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh/) tools.

Answer (score 1):

So, by default Mac does not support APT commands (APT and YUM are available in linux).
if you want to install ffmpeg, you can follow the instructions on following link:
https://sites.duke.edu/ddmc/2013/12/30/install-ffmpeg-on-a-mac/

instead of apt install, what is used in mac is homebrew or macports for more knowledge please refer to the following link:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-apt-get-or-yum-on-mac-os-x